# System.Web.HttpUnhandledException

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, system.web, httpapplication, handleerror

I am working on web application which is using lot of Ajax controls. I am not the developer of the application. I working on rectifying this issue. This application keeps throwing the error message below:

```
Source: System.Web
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Stack trace:
    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    at ASP.whyfj_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I tried searching on google but didn't get any solution. I am not facing this problem in local server and main thing this is that its  random error. Some time same pages works very well.

Server : 2008, IIS 7.5

Please help

Comment: Think you need to stick a few breakpoints to see what's happening. Bit difficult to work it out from that alone.

Comment: Change `EnableViewStateMac` to `false` for the page and check if it still happens

Answer (score 4):

That's not the stacktrace of the actual exception, just the stacktrace of the Error handling framework. Unless you can find the innerException in the event logs, you won't be able to fix this easily.

Approach the developer.